# .NET Core 2.2 + Angular 7 "xhr_streaming" Never Ending

Tags: angular, websocket, .net-core, single-page-application, sockjs

I am setting up a .NET Core Web API backend, with an Angular 7 SPA for the frontend. I am using Microsoft's SpaServices, and StaticFiles packages to link the two under one project.

When I run the web app, the console tab shows a sockjs WebSocket warning, and the network tab shows something called "xhr_streaming" from sockjs that stays open forever.

Is this behavior normal? Or have I not setup/configured something correctly?

I have not done anything to the project except generate the Web API using Rider, and the Angular 7 app using the Angular CLI. I cannot seem to find much related the this problem online, it's possible I am not searching correctly though.

Here is my startup in the web API. I've focused it on only the configurations I have done to link it with Angular.

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Rest of ConfigureServices are unrelated

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                // RootPath = "ClientApp/dist"
                configuration.RootPath = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<SpaConfig>>().Value.RootPath;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Rest of Configure is irrelevant

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "default",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer("start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

There really isn't anything to show from the Angular side of things as I haven't changed a thing after I generated it with `ng new`.

Basically I am just wondering if this behavior is expected, or if I have done something wrong.

Here are some screenshots of the warning, and network reading:
[image: Network reading]

And the warning:
[image: Warning]

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I called a function returning a promise from the constructor of a service. The function call consisted an api get-request. Once I removed the function call, the xhr_streaming stopped being a never ending request.